# No audio to/from snaps after update

Tags: sound, snap, 23.10, wireplumber

```
$ wsl --version  
WSL version: 2.1.5.0  
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2  
WSLg version: 1.0.60  
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105  
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511  
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp  
Windows version: 10.0.22631.3371
```

Windows 11 Version 23H2 (OS Build 22631.3371)

I'm having problems with sound to and from snap apps.

If I install WSL Ubuntu 22.04 from Microsoft Store the sound to/from snaps works right (apps tested are Firefox and my own guitarfinetune). Also if I upgrade the distribution to Ubuntu 23.10 the sound to/from snap apps keeps working.

but if I install `sudo apt install -y update-manager` no sound gets through to/from snap apps. In apps not installed as snap the sound works fine.

It seems to be if `wireplumber` is installed that the sound to/from snap apps is broken!

How do I repair the sound system to/from snap apps?